# Notepad++ remove all non regex'd text

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

I have a large list of urls that has a unique numeric string in each, the string falls between a `/` and a `?` I would like to remove all other text from notepad++ that are not these strings. for example
`www.website.com/dsw/fv3n24nv1e4121v/123456789012?fwe=32432fdwe23f3` would end up as only `123456789012`

I have figured out that the following regex `\b\d{12}\b` will get me the 12 digits, now I just need to remove all of the information that falls each side. I have had a look and found some posts that suggest replace with `\t$1` , `$1\n`
 , `$1` , and `/1` however all of these do the exact oposite of what I want and just remove the 12 digit string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex and replace it with empty string,

```
^[^ ]*\/|\?[^ ]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3jsNUn/1)

**Explanation:**

- `^[^ ]*\/` --> Matches anything expect space from start of string till it finds a `/`
- `\?[^ ]*$` --> Similarly, this matches anything except space starting from `?` till end of input.

Comment: Maybe mention that the checkbox "`.` matches newline" should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*/([^?]+).*$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *UNCHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
    /           # a slash
    ([^?\r\n]+) # group 1, 1 or more any character that is not ? or line break
    .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Result for given example:**

```
123456789012
```